# How to save wfdb plot as an image in local directory?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, waveform

I want to be able to save wfdb ECG plots as an image file locally to be used for image processing processes. I am using Jupyter notebook on Anaconda, in python programming language.

I have tried plt.savefig() to save the image, and it does generate a file. However when I open the said file, there is no image.

```
import wfdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

record =wfdb.rdrecord(r'D:\User\qt-database-1.0.0\sel33', sampfrom=0, sampto=999, channels = [1])
#annotation = wfdb.rdann(r'D:\User\qt-database-1.0.0\sel33', 'atr', sampto=1000)

wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record, 
               #annotation=annotation, 
               plot_sym=True,
               time_units='seconds', 
               title='',
               figsize=(20,3), 
               ecg_grids='')

plt.savefig("foo.png")
```

The file is also a continuous waveform, and I intend to create a set of images from the waveform. Is there any way to do this?

P.S. I did manually save the image using snipping tool, however I have found it to be inefficient and time consuming. A code-oriented solution would be a major help.

Comment: Saving a figure as a png is really not going to help you recover anything later.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand, what do you mean by not recovering anything later?

Comment: If you are attempting to get information from a PNG image, that's a bad idea. Why are you not using the plotted waveform data directly?

Comment: Also, what does `plot_wfdb` return exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Within the wfdb.plot() function, there is an optional parameter called return_fig which returns the matplotlib figure that you are trying to save. If you change your code to have wfdb.plot() return the figure, you should be able to save it.

```
import wfdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

record = wfdb.rdrecord(r'D:\User\qt-database-1.0.0\sel33', sampfrom=0, sampto=999, channels = [1])
#annotation = wfdb.rdann(r'D:\User\qt-database-1.0.0\sel33', 'atr', sampto=1000)

myFigure = wfdb.plot_wfdb(record=record, 
               #annotation=annotation, 
               plot_sym=True,
               time_units='seconds', 
               title='',
               figsize=(20,3), 
               ecg_grids='')

myFigure.savefig("foo.png")
```