# wfdb in python script returns `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert WFDB formatted data to csv (using the wfdb package), but I do get an `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds` error in the python script, which I do not understand.

I am using the `infant10_ecg.*` data from here: https://physionet.org/content/picsdb/1.0.0/

This is the script I'm using:

```
import wfdb # WaveForm-Database package. A library of tools for reading, writing, and processing WFDB signals and annotations.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob


dat_files=glob.glob('*.dat')
df=pd.DataFrame(data=dat_files)
df.to_csv("files_list.csv",index=False,header=None)
files=pd.read_csv("files_list.csv",header=None)

for i in range(1,len(files)+1):
  recordname=str(files.iloc[[i]])
  print(recordname[:-4])
  recordname_new=recordname[-7:-4]
  record = wfdb.rdsamp(recordname_new)
  record=np.asarray(record[0])
  path=recordname_new+".csv"
  np.savetxt(path,record,delimiter=",")
  print("Files done: %s/%s"% (i,len(files)))

print("\nAll files done!")
```

Comment: Please include the full error message / stack trace.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with wfdb. You simply need to use zero-based indexing: `for i in range(len(files)`. Then again, it would be even simpler to just iterate over the filenames directly: `files = glob.glob('*.dat'); for i, recordname in enumerate(files)`. The dataframe is serving no useful purpose at all.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you. With changing the range the script is working but there is no result data in the csv file.

Comment: @user3142695 Why are you doing `recordname[-7:-4]`? All you need to do is remove the *.dat* extension before passing the filepath to wfdg. It's best to use an absolute path when creating the list of files, and then use either [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) or [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) to manipulate the filepaths. Then you can do e.g. `files = glob.glob('*.dat'); for i, filepath in enumerate(files): recordname = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0]; record = wfdb.rdsamp(recordname); ... path = recordname+'.csv'`.

Comment: @user3142695 I just had a look at one of the smallest ecg files (84.5 MiB), and the first record contains about ***45 million*** float values. When that is dumped with `np.savetxt`, it will create a 1.1 GiB file. Are you sure you want to do this? Processing a csv file of that size will be *extemely* inefficient. The wfdb package is optimised for handling this kind of data, so why don't you make full use of it? What exactly are you trying to achieve by dumping the raw data to a csv file?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you very much for having a look at this. I'm very unfamiliar with this kind of data. You are right, the data is huge, but I need csv values for further processing. But I do not need the complete dataset. Just 5 minutes are enough. I need this real ecg data to get displayed on a monitor simulator. Maybe it is possible to convert only a specific part of the record?

Comment: @user3142695 But ***why exactly*** do you need the data in csv format? What ***specific*** kind of processing are you intending to do? The [wfdb API](https://wfdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) already provides many different methods for processing the data (e.g. the creation of matplotlib figures - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668241/984421)). I highly doubt you have a use-case that isn't already catered for in some way. What specific features do you think are lacking?

Comment: I need to build a monitor simulator, like in this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/4fn77k Therefore I need some ecg data from infants. As far as I see the data which is used is a simple value array. The next step I have to get done is to change the data "live". So I need to change the frequency e.g. from 150/min to 100/min on the fly. I thought of calculating the array values based on the initial values...

Comment: @user3142695 That doesn't explain why you need to dump the data to a csv file, nor why you can't use wfdb itself to generate the desired data.